# How should I model a horses pedigree in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to model a horses pedigree in mongodb.

[image]

I've conducted some research on the internet and have uncovered several potential approaches:

1. Array of ancestors
2. graph
3. simple relationships {_id: "Cigar", sire: "Palace Music", dam: "Solar Slew", Sire's Sire: ...}
4. Tree Structure with Nested Sets

I'm hoping to get input from some more with experience than me on both the tradeoffs of various approaches given my use cases below:

My use cases follow:

- **Presentation**: I will want to display or give the user the option to
  display the horses pedigree anytime a user queries a particular
  horse.
- Traverse/Query: The ability to easily traverse or query the pedigree (by ancestry) to return a particular horse in the pedigree (i.e. return all broodmare sires wit one offspring with more than 5 turf wins)
- **Performance**:  Its imperative that pedigree queries are very performant.
- **Ratings**: use the pedigree data in conjunction with race results to develop pedigree ratings.**strong text**
- **Analysis**:  I will want to conduct analysis on horses pedigrees relative to win and may try to answer such questions as:

  - Is a horse with Northern Dancer as his great grand sire more likely to win its first turf race.
  - What are the Top 10 Sires (Dams, Grand Sires or Grand Dams) for producing winner on a yielding turf course.

Additional information: I plan on developing this application on the MEAN stack.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: **Performance** is the hard bit. Good luck.

Comment: Why so? Too much data?

Comment: No, it's just that when I start to think about querying that structure, it's an awful query, so I imagine it's something that will take a bit of effort.

Answer (score 0):

The data you have is very clearly a binary tree structure. Each horse is a node in the tree, with two child nodes representing the horse's parents (ironic!)

[Tutorial: Model Tree Structures in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/). You can insert each horse (starting furthest up the ancestry chain) with a list of the ids for the horse's "children" (which are the horse's dam and sire).

I admit that I'm not familiar enough with MongoDB to give you specific code for your DB queries, but as Mongo is capable of hierarchical data storage, a tree should offer few to no  problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I came across this in my research.  My concern here was that I wasn't differentiating between sires and dams, just parents. With this approach I thought it would be dicey traversing the tree to get to a particular ancestor, but I could be mistaken.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user365853, Storing the horse's gender should be enough to differentiate between sire and dam. Alternatively, you could store sire and dam explicitly, rather than storing both together in a list. Eg: `{id: "Nearco", sire: null, dam: null}`, `{id: "Lady Angela", sire: null, dam: null}`, `{id: "Noarctic", sire: "Nearco", dam: "Lady Angela"}`